# ionic cordova native plugins are missing in --release build

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic-native

I have an ionic v3 app that seems to work fine if I run it with `ionic cordova run android --device` or if I build with `ionic cordova build android --prod` and then install the `app-debug.apk` on the device. 
However, if I do `ionic cordova build android --release --prod` then sign the unsigned apk and install the signed apk on device it looks like all the native plugins are missing. from logcat I can see a bunch of messages like:

```
Native: tried calling LocalNotifications.on, but the LocalNotifications plugin is not installed.
Native: tried calling StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString, but the StatusBar plugin is not installed.
```

Here's the output of `ionic info` :

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.5.0 (/home/foysal/n/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/foysal/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.11.0 (/home/foysal/n/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

Comment: Make sure you are using plugins after cordova platform ready event

Comment: Thanks @dhavalcengg but I can confirm that all plugin stuff are called after ready event.